# DataGridView OnKeyPressed behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to make my DGV to not scroll when user press Ctrl+PgDown. I want to scroll some other control instead. The problem is there is some different behaviour whether some cell in edit mode or not.

*1st case*. When there is no edit mode we have the following chain of events:

1. DGV KeyDown
2. DGV Scroll
3. DGV KeyUp

So I handle DGV KeyDown. Heare I can both detect if Ctrl+PgDown is pressed and stop DGV Scroll to occur.

*2nd case*. When there is edit mode and I press Ctrl+PgDown we have the following chain of events (Note that in edit mode DGV dynamicly creates TextBox control):

1. in txtbox_PreviewKeyDown Key = ControlKey Ctrl = True
2. in txtbox_KeyDown Key = ControlKey Ctrl = True
3. in txtbox_PreviewKeyDown Key = Next Ctrl = True
4. in dGV_Scroll
5. in dGVEditor_KeyUp Key = Next Ctrl = True
6. in dGVEditor_KeyUp Key = ControlKey Ctrl = False
7. in dGVEditor_KeyUp Key = ControlKey Ctrl = False

Also I track txtbox_KeyUp and txtbox_KeyPress but they never fire.

So in this case I can handle Ctrl+PgDown only in PreviewKeyDown but cannot stop it to fire the scroll event.

*3rd case*. The txtbox_KeyDown do not fire on PageDown key if user presses it first (no changes been made in edited cell). When PageDown (or Ctrl+PgDown) is pressed after some changes been made in the cell I track the following:

1. txtbox_PreviewKeyDown Key = ControlKey Ctrl = True
2. txtbox_KeyDown Key = ControlKey Ctrl = True
3. txtbox_PreviewKeyDown Key = Next Ctrl = True
4. txtbox_KeyDown Key = Next Ctrl = True
5. txtbox_KeyUp Key = Next Ctrl = True
6. txtbox_KeyUp Key = ControlKey Ctrl = False

So in this case I can handle Ctrl+PgDown in txtbox_KeyDown and can stop the scroll.

My question is how to handle things in the second scenario? Is there some way (some event) to handle Ctrl+PgDown in all cases by one event handler? In my case I use three: dGV_KeyDown, dGV_EditingControlShowing (to configurate catching the txtbox_KeyDown) and txtbox_KeyDown at the same time.